# How to remove the blank field for Sitecore Droplink and Droplist

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype, validation

In Sitecore 9.0, when I create a Droplink or Droplist Sitecore generates a "blank" selection. For example I have a Droplink from Monday to Sunday, the first option will be a blank selection.

How can we remove this blank selection?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. That would mean that you cannot clear selection. And what is more, what should be the default value then? Which one should be selected by default?

Comment: You can select a default value from the data-source. However, the business user can still select the blank value.

Comment: I would recommend setting a field validation so that the content author gets a warning (or error) if they leave it empty (i.e. select the blank option). https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/

Comment: There are two workarounds to handle this but I would like to remove the blank field. First workaround is to add required field validation. If the user selects a blank and tries to save a popup message displays. The business user needs to select a value. I did not like this workaround.

Comment: The second workaround is that to select a checkbox on the template to reset to the default value. If the business user selects a blank value and saves the droplist automatically resets to default value. I liked this workaround more.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot completely remove the blank option. Instead, I would recommend setting the **Required** field validator on your field so that a user gets a warning (or cannot save it) if they leave the field blank.

## Add the validator

1. In the Content Editor, select your field item in Sitecore
2. Scroll down to the **Validation Rules** section and add the **Required** item to all four validation fields:

   [image: validation rules fields]
3. Save your field

## Extra credit: prevent the editor from saving

If you want to prevent content authors from saving the item at all if there is no value selected, you can create a copy of the default **Required** validator and increase the error level of its failures.

1. In the Content Editor, select the **Required** field validator

   - `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Required`
2. Copy the item to a folder of validation rules you manage
3. In the **Parameters** field, add `Result=FatalError`
4. Add this new validator to your field instead of the default **Required** validator